# How do I set the number of workspaces without CCSM?

Tags: unity, workspaces

It's been an issue for quite some time to set the number of different desktops (or workspaces if you like) in the new Ubuntu Natty Narwhal (using unity).

Some guys figured out a way to overcome it by using the compiz-config(CCSM).
For some reason it seems that the CCSM doesn't really work for me. I change the number of desktops, and the expo but it won't work.

Comment: Did you change the horizontal and vertical

Comment: Does expo not work or does it just still have 4 workspaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why ccsm wouldn't work, but if you really want to do it on the command line, you can directly access gconf.

Open Terminal and try these commands.

Running this in a terminal will tell you your current setting:

```
gconftool --get /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/hsize
```

Running this will change your horizontal and vertical size to 3:

```
gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/hsize --type=int 3
gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/vsize --type=int 3
```

If you have multiple screens or other complications, then this might not work.

Comment: And if you're looking for things like this in the future, you can open `gconf-editor` (called Configuration Editor in the menu) and search for relevant keywords. Ignore anything under `/schemas/`

Answer (score 6):

If you still can not use CCSM you could also add an indicator. See the image:

[image: image1]

Add `ppa:geod/ppa-geod` to your Software Sources, update and then search for `indicator workspaces` or do a `sudo apt-get install indicator-workspaces`

References:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Answer (score 2):

Did you change the horizontal and vertical size? These change the number of workspaces. I would have expected it to be 'number of desktops' but it is the other 2 you need to change ;-)

[image: Desktop Size in general options]

Like the image shows mine is 3 by 2.

Comment: Tried that already. (my mistake for writing "number of desktops")

Comment: Woah. Why is your Number of desktops set to 4? Does that do anything?

Comment: It shows a 3x3 desktops. But when I change between one desktop to another (via a ctrl+arrow_key) , I see only 6 available in a row.
and when I use the "change desktop" button the new Unity bar, there's place for 9 windows filled by only 6.

gconftool --get /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/hsize
gconftool --get /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/vsize

both return 3.

It's kinda weird.

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with anything, but when I check the /apps/... path in gconf-editor It says "This key has no schema".

Comment: @pydave: no does not seem to work. That one is for having multiple desktops on 1 viewport (you could have 8 or 12 viewports with 2 or 3 cubes each holding 4 sets of workspaces). I wanted to see if this works again but this got removed in hardy and never came back (due to too many problems)

Comment: It seems that compiz wasn't working at all.. I had to use "compiz --replace" for it to run.
Do I need to add it to startup applications now or there's a nicer way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

a round-about way, but easy enough is the following:

open a terminal and type in

gnome-panel

the top and bottom original gnome menu bars appear and on the bottom one you will see the workspaces icon which you can then right-click and properties in the usual manner.

close the terminal and if the menu bars remain, just right click them each individually and remove them... click on your workspace icon in the unity side-menu and you will now see the amount of desktops you set.

Comment: The best answer do far. I do not like those "advanced-user" answers.

Comment: thanx... i usually fiddle till i find a way, and along the way I exhaust all options...

Answer (score 0):

See the section on "Change Desktop Size" at http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/04/12-things-i-did-after-installing-new.html