# Is it possible to add a desktop in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: customization, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set the number of workspaces without CCSM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38801/how-do-i-set-the-number-of-workspaces-without-ccsm)

By default Ubuntu 11.10 has 4 desktops. I want to add two more desktops (I want to obtain a 3x2 grid). Is it possible? How to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm). If you haven't got it already, you can download it from the Software Centre.

Next, go to General Options > Desktop Size, and adjust the Horizontal Virtual Size and Vertical Virtual Size to achieve the grid you want.